# im trying to implement a circular array deque in java

Tags: java, circular-dependency, arraydeque

This is what I got coding so far but the tests keep failing, I can provide the test file if someone can help. thank you!

The requirements are that the front should start at position zero and rear at position length -1.

Also in an empty Queue, rear is one position counter-clockwise to front and in a full queue, rear is two positions counter-clockwise to front.

In our implementation of Dequeue, there is no count variable to keep track of the number of elements. Instead, to distinguish a full-queue from an empty queue, we never allow the queue to get completely full.

A full queue is one with exactly one empty spot in the array. That way we can distinguish an empty queue and full queue by looking at the relative positions of front and rear.

```
import  java.util.*;
public class Dequeue<E> {
    private E elements[];
    private int front, rear;
    private static final int INITIAL_CAPACITY = 5;

    /**Creates an empty dequeue
     */

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public Dequeue() {
        elements = (E[]) new Object[INITIAL_CAPACITY];
        front = 0;
        rear = elements.length-1; // rear will point one position counter clockwise front
    }
    /** Increases the size of the queue when the queue is full
     * 
     */

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private void reallocate() {
        E[] queue = (E[]) new Object[INITIAL_CAPACITY *10 ]; // expand the size of the queue by creating a new queue with size 10 times the initial size
        int current = front; // local pointer pointing at front
        for (int i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
            queue[i] = elements[current]; // new queue gets all the elements of the old queue
            current = (current + 1) % elements.length; // pointer moves to the next queue spot, clockwise
        }
        front = 0;
        rear = elements.length-1;
        elements = queue;
    } 

    /** Adds an item to the front of this dequeue
     * @param anEntry the item to be placed at the front of the dequeue.
     * @return true (always successful)
     * Precondition:None
     * Postcondition: the new item is the first item on the dequeue
     */


    public boolean addFront(E anEntry) {
        if (size() == elements.length - 1) { // check if queue is full
            reallocate();
        } 
        else if(empty()) {
            elements[front] = anEntry;
            front = (front + 1) % elements.length;
            return true;}
        else { 
            if (front == rear) {
                front = (rear +1)%elements.length +1;


            }
            elements[front] = anEntry;
            front = (front + 1) % elements.length;

            return true; 
            }


    }







/** Adds an item to the rear of this dequeue
 * @param anEntry - is the item to be placed at the end of the dequeue.
 * @return true (always successful)
 * Precondition:None
 * Postcondition:the new item is the last item on the dequeue
 */

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public boolean addRear(E anEntry) {
    if (size() == elements.length - 1) {
        E[] queue = (E[]) new Object[INITIAL_CAPACITY * 10];
        int current = front;
        for (int i = 0; i < size(); i++) {
            queue[i] = elements[current];
            current = (current + 1) % elements.length;
        }
        front = 0;
        rear = size() + 1;
        elements = queue;
    } 
    if (empty()) {
        rear = front = 0;
        elements[rear] = anEntry;   
    }
    else {
        rear = (rear + 1) % elements.length; //moves clockwise
        elements[rear] = anEntry;   
    }
    return true;
}

/** Removes the item from the front of the dequeue
 *  @return The front item from the dequeue.
 *  @throws NoSuchElementException  if the dequeue is empty
 *  Precondition: The dequeue is not empty
 *  Postcondition:The front item on the dequeue has been removed and the dequeue has one less element
 */
public E removeFront() {
    if (empty()) throw new NoSuchElementException();
    E item;
    if (size() == 1) {
        item = elements[front];//stores the front element
        rear = -1;
        front = 0;      
    }
    else {
        item = elements[front];
        front = (front + 1) % elements.length; //moves clockwise, element is now removed        
    }
    return item;
}

/** Removes the item from the back of the dequeue
 *  @return The last item from the dequeue.
 *  @throws NoSuchElementException  if the dequeue is empty
 * Precondition: the dequeue is not empty
 * Postcondition: the last item on the dequeue has been removed and the dequeue has one less element
 */

public E removeRear() {
    if (empty()) throw new NoSuchElementException();
    E item;
    if (size() == 1) {
        item = elements[rear]; //stores the rear element
        front = 0; 
        rear = -1; //element now removed
    }
    else if (rear == 0) {
        item = elements[rear];
        rear = elements.length; //element now removed

    }
    else {
        item = elements[rear];
        rear -= 1; //moves counter clockwise, element removed
    }
    return item;
}

/** Returns the object at the front of the dequeue without removing it from the dequeue
 * @return the object at the front of the dequeue if the dequeue is not empty
 * @throws NoSuchElementException - if the dequeue is empty.
 * Precondition: none
 * Postcondition: The dequeue remains unchanged
 */

public E peekFront() {
    if (empty())
        throw new NoSuchElementException();
    else {
        return elements[front];
    }
}

/** Returns the object at the rear of the dequeue without removing it from the dequeue.
 * @return the object at the back of the dequeue if the dequeue is not empty.
 * @throws NoSuchElementException  if the dequeue is empty.
 * Precondition: none
 * Postcondition: The dequeue remains unchanged.
 */

public E peekRear() {
    if (empty()) throw new NoSuchElementException();
    else {
        return elements[rear];
    }
}

/** Checks if dequeue is empty
 * @return true if the dequeue is empty; false otherwise.
 */

public boolean empty() {
    return ((rear + 1)% elements.length == front);
}

/**
 * @return the number of elements in this dequeue.
 */

public int size() {
    if (empty())
        return 0;
    else {
        if(front>rear) {
            return(((elements.length - front) + (rear + 1)) % elements.length);

        }else if(rear>=front) { return ((rear -front + 1)% elements.length);}


    }
}

/**
 * @return an iterator for the dequeue.
 */
public Iterator<E> iterator(){
    return new myIterator();
}


/**private inner class to implement the Iterator<E> interface
 *
 */
public class myIterator implements Iterator<E> {
    private int forward;
    /**
     * Initializes the myIterator object to reference the first dequeue
     * element
     */
    public myIterator() {
        forward = front;
    }

    /**Returns true if there are more elements in the dequeue to access 
     * else return false
     * 
     */
    public boolean hasNext() {
        if (forward == (rear + 1) % elements.length)
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    /**Returns the next element in the queue 
     * pre: forward references the next
     * element to access 
     * post: forward is incremented by the remainder
     * @return The element with subscript value
     * 
     */
    public E next() {
        if (!hasNext())
            throw new NoSuchElementException();
        E returnValue = elements[forward];
        forward = (forward + 1) % elements.length;
        return returnValue;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: It would be nice if you could format your text.  Please add a description of a faliure case or two, otherwise we are just left to guess at what your error is.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Unfortunately, you haven't really indicated what your question is other than a general plea to debug your code for you. Have you individually tested the various methods? Do you know which ones are working properly and which aren't?

Comment: i can provide the test file and show you where it fails too.